# Do I need to remove React Native event listeners on app close?

Tags: react-native

I have a single app state listener that's being set via saga from the redux store root file. This should happen only once in a lifetime of the app.
Do I need to care about removing the said listener when the app's being terminated? And if so how can I proceed without depending on lifecycle methods of the components?

Comment: all listeners are automatically terminated on app termination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All event listeners are automatically closed when app stops, or gets killed. SO you need not worry about them after the app is terminated.

Altough sometimes you want the listeners to stop on after navigating away from a page you can always use , `componentWillUnmount`.

hope it helps. feel free for doubt

Comment: This definitely seems like a logical outcome but maybe you have a link to the docs? I couldn't find